# postgres synonym and prefix results together

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have synonyms: lake lac loch
When I do fts in postgres for 'lake', I want to get all words that contain 'lake', 'lac' and 'loch' (which I have using synonyms either as .syn file or .rules file). However, I also want to get the words that start with 'lake', like 'lakefield'. If I use synonyms I don't get prefix matches, when I don't use synonyms I get prefix matches ... How can I get both? Is there a way of turning off synonyms so I make one quesry to get synonyms and one ignoring them? I tried with 'like' and 'position' but it is way too slow.

.rules have:
lake lac loch
loch lake lac
lac lake loch

.syn have:
lake yyyyy
lac yyyyy
loch yyyyy

I tried both, but same problem. If I map all synonyms to one of them in .syn file:
lake lake 
lac lake 
loch lake

... I will get 'lakefield' but not 'lacombe' (and I need them all to work with prefix).

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.

The query is:

```
select 
    *, 
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('location', name), to_tsquery('location', 'lac:*'),16) as ftsrank
from profile_name 
where iso_code='en-CA' 
  AND to_tsvector('location', name) @@ to_tsquery('location', 'lac:*') 
  AND ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('location', name), to_tsquery('location', 'lac:*'),16) >= 0
order by ftsrank desc
```

The `profile` table has a `name` field that I want to search against.

Thanks,
Zorica

Comment: You should post the SQL statement you are using so that we can help you with that

Comment: Thanks Soren, valid point. Here you go:
`select *, ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('location', name), to_tsquery('location', 'lac:*'),16) as ftsrank from profile_name
where iso_code='en-CA' AND
       to_tsvector('location', name) @@ to_tsquery('location', 'lac:*') AND
      ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('location', name), to_tsquery('location', 'lac:*'),16) >= 0
order by ftsrank desc`

'profile' table has 'name' field that I like to search against.

Comment: That's a very interesting problem. I don't know the answer off the top of my head. If you don't get a reply here, please post a detailed question to the pgsql-general mailing list with a subject like *"Combining prefix matching and synonyms in tsearch?"* . Include a link to this question at the bottom, and if you do post on -general, please comment here to say so, that way others can find it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:
I've added a new fts (full text search) configuration that doesn't use synonyms and referred to that one in to_tsquery on the keyword user typed in to search for. For my example above, it looks like this:

```
select 
    *, 
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('location', name), to_tsquery('location_nosyn', 'lac:*'),16) as ftsrank
from profile_name 
where iso_code='en-CA' 
  AND to_tsvector('location', name) @@ to_tsquery('location_nosyn', 'lac:*') 
  AND ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('location', name), to_tsquery('location_nosyn', 'lac:*'),16) >= 0
order by ftsrank desc
```

... where 'location_nosyn' is mentioned fts configuration that doesn't recognize synonyms. Notice that I still use synonyms for database field 'name' so it will grab all synonyms from the db. However, not using synonyms for a keyword keeps partial matches working (if user entered 'lac' they will get synonym words like 'Lake' but they will also get 'Lacey' but NOT 'Lakewood' ... which is exactly what I need).

Hope this will help someone else with the similar problem.
Thanks to everyone who replied!

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use the query rewrite feature?

```
select
ts_rewrite('lake'::tsquery, 'lake'::tsquery, 'lake:* | lac | loch'::tsquery) @@ 'lake'::tsvector, --true
ts_rewrite('lake'::tsquery, 'lake'::tsquery, 'lake:* | lac | loch'::tsquery) @@ 'loch'::tsvector, --true
ts_rewrite('lake'::tsquery, 'lake'::tsquery, 'lake:* | lac | loch'::tsquery) @@ 'lakefield'::tsvector --true
```

You can keep your query re-writes in database tables too.

Comment: Thanks Neil. This looks like an alternative to using synonym extensions. As I've already found a solution I am posting it as an answer - not saying yours is not ... I just haven't tried ... :) Thanks!